# Make the height of a background image related to another div height

Tags: css

I am curious if there is an easy way to make the height of the image in the right div to be equal to the height of the left div, which can have different height values. I managed to achieve this by using JavaScript, but I was wondering if it can be done purely based on CSS.

The idea behind this was to make the image centered and just show as much of the height and the width of the div as possible without resizing the image. However, as I am posting this it didn't work quite as expected.

```
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: center;
```

```css
#body{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}

#main{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 90vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:#fff;
}

#left{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
 }
 
 #right{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    background-color:pink
 }
 
    #right img{
        width: 10%; /* had to add that just to make it look presentable */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: center;
    }
    
    
#author{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

#author a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="main">
      <div id="left">
          We do not know the exact height of the div, but we want the image to be the exact size like this div.
      </div>
      <div id="right">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494961104209-3c223057bd26?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2302&q=80" alt="containers">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="author">Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@guibolduc?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Guillaume Bolduc</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com/s/photos/containers?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a></div>
```

Comment: When you mean "exact size", do you mean fill the height OR width (preserves aspect ratio) or stretch to height AND weight (may distort aspect ratio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without needing to use background images, we can use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).  To do so, absolutely position `<img>` and ensure it is stretched to fill its parent container dimensions, and then use `object-fit` to determine how the image should be fitted into those bounds.

The [`object-fit` property is very much widely supported today](https://caniuse.com/object-fit): all evergreen browsers support it, with the expected omission of IE11 of course.

The property accepts several values, but only two of them are probably of any relevance to your use-case:

- `object-fit: contain` to ensure that the entirety of the image is visible. In your case, as the container is much wider than it is tall, the image will be fitted by height:

[image: Object fit: contain]

- `object-fit: cover` to ensure that the image is stretched while retaining aspect ratio

[image: Object fit: cover]

See proof-of-concept below, using `object-fit: contain`:

```css
#body{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}

#main{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 90vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:#fff;
}

#left{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
 }
 
 #right{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    background-color:pink
 }
 
    #right img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
    
    
#author{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

#author a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="main">
      <div id="left">
          We do not know the exact height of the div, but we want the image to be the exact size like this div.
      </div>
      <div id="right">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494961104209-3c223057bd26?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2302&q=80" alt="containers">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="author">Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@guibolduc?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Guillaume Bolduc</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com/s/photos/containers?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a></div>
```

Comment: @GeorgeSmith Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

can you use a background image?
add this css to #right

```
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494961104209-3c223057bd26?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2302&q=80);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your post! I can use a background image. However, now the height is fine, but the width of the image is way shorter than the width of the div.

Answer (score 1):

See the snippet below. Instead of using an `img` element inside, you can use a `background-image` by CSS. To avoid hard-coding image path, you could use an inline CSS custom property to use multiple different images as needed.

NOTE:

- `background-size: contain;` makes the image best fit the container without cropping anything out.
- `background-position: center;` and `background-repeat: no-repeat;` ensure that image appears at the center without creating a repeat pattern.
- `style="--bg: url(....)"` portion is what makes it repeatable, as it's picked up in the CSS.

  ```css
  #body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  #main {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 90vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #left {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  #right {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
    background-image: var(--bg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

  }

  #author {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #author a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="body">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="left">
        We do not know the exact height of the div, but we want the image to be the exact size like this div.
      </div>
      <div id="right" style="--bg: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494961104209-3c223057bd26?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2302&q=80)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="author">Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@guibolduc?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Guillaume Bolduc</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com/s/photos/containers?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a></div>
  ```